# What's the endpoint running at `include:spf.example.com` as seen in an SPF record in DNS?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, spf

How can I run an SPF `include` endpoint for my organisation?

In this example, the SPF record for a domain permits hosts included via the `spf.example.com` list, and prohibits everything else:

```
"v=spf1 include:spf.example.com ~all"
```

Use case: I have slightly more than the max 10 hosts permitted in SPF by RFC4408, and I would prefer to run my own `spf.example.com` as a single `include` in the DNS record.

What software or architecture can I run at `spf.example.com` to provide this?

Thank you.

Comment: Not an answer, but it sounds like in your situation a `redirect` modifier would be preferable to the `include` mechanism, see RFC 7208, towards the end of section 5.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to run any software, the "include" directive literally includes the SPF result for the stated domain name.

You simply need to create a SPF record (i.e. a TXT record with a valid SPF syntax) in the DNS zone "spf.example.com"; in that record you will mention all your allowed mail senders using IP addresses, host names or whatever.

When you put `include:spf.example.com` in another SPF record, the SPF result for `spf.example.com` will be included.

This all happens using DNS, no other software is involved or required.